# Transform XML with XSLT with complex XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having some difficulty transforming this XML using XSLT. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Projects>
   <Project>
      <Tasks>
         <Task>
            <Deliverables>
               <Deliverable>
                  <Product>
                     <ProductCode>
                        <![CDATA[123456]]>
                        <Package>
                           <![CDATA[CASE]]>
                           <UUID><![CDATA[037XXXXXX21]]></UUID>
                        </Package>
                     </ProductCode>
                     <ProductCode>
                        <![CDATA[222333]]>
                        <Package>
                           <![CDATA[ITEM]]>
                           <UUID><![CDATA[000XXXXXX52723]]></UUID>
                        </Package>
                     </ProductCode>
                     <ProductCode>
                        <![CDATA[444555]]>
                        <Package>
                           <![CDATA[SHRINKWRAP]]>
                           <UUID><![CDATA[111XXXXXX52723]]></UUID>
                        </Package>
                     </ProductCode>
                  </Product>
               </Deliverable>
            </Deliverables>
         </Task>
      </Tasks>
   </Project>
</Projects>
```

I would like to transform it so the results look like this:

```html
<RESULTSET>
  <ROW>
    <COL>
      <DATA>123456</DATA>
    </COL>
    <COL>
      <DATA>CASE</DATA>
    </COL>
    <COL>
      <DATA>037XXXXXX21</DATA>
    </COL>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <COL>
      <DATA>222333</DATA>
    </COL>
    <COL>
      <DATA>ITEM</DATA>
    </COL>
    <COL>
      <DATA>000XXXXXX52723</DATA>
    </COL>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <COL>
      <DATA>444555</DATA>
    </COL>
    <COL>
      <DATA>SHRINKWRAP (SW)</DATA>
    </COL>
    <COL>
      <DATA>111XXXXXX52723</DATA>
    </COL>
  </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

Here is my template and I don't know what needs to change so it will transform properly.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<!--<xsl:template match="Projects/Project/Tasks/Task/Deliverables/Deliverable">-->
   <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match=">
<xsl:apply-templates select="ProductCode" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: You should at least try to implement something and then ask specific questions. You cannt expect that someone programs the transformation for you!

Comment: Your XSL is not valid XML. You wrote: `<xsl:template match=">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try something like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
     <xsl:template match="/">
        <resultSet> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </resultSet> 
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="ProductCode">
        <row>
            <xsl:call-template name="t1"/>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="t1">
        <col>
            <data>
                <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
            </data>
        </col>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="t1"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: thank you. Your solution works very well. I knew there had to be a template, nested in a template, but I had a tough time finding good examples. It makes a lot more sense to me know. Much appreciated.